# How to load content from external pages using bootstrap 4.4.x modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to load content from external page into *Bootstrap 4.4* modal. Here is my [demo](https://www.bootply.com/DjLRlzBFNs)

JS:

```
$('#theModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

            var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
            var modal = $(this);

            // load content from HTML string
            //modal.find('.modal-body').html("Nice modal body baby...");

            // or, load content from value of data-remote url
            modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.data("remote"));

        });
```

HTML:

```
 <ul class="nav flex-row" id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/" class="nav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/" class="nav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#theModal" class="nav-link" data-remote="https://www.lipsum.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal">Modal</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">My modal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ... remote content from "data-remote" loads here ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - what specific problem do you face? You want us to explain how requests works...? What have you tried by yourself?

Comment: Copied code verbatim. The link is kept.

Comment: When i click modal link, It doesn't load content from external page. for example if i use jquery codes like `modal.find('.modal-body').html("Nice modal body baby...");` , It works. when i use `modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.data("remote"));`, it doesn't work.

Comment: it seems that jquery function **load()** doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I fixed the problem. In my body tag, I had bootstrap's scripts like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What I did was, I removed

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this script entry from the body tag and added jQuery cdn link to header tag.

It works well for me.